# Comparing ReadLine to String or viceversa

Tags: c#

Right off the bat:

So I am comparing if user is inputing a right answer.
Code looks something like this:

```
While(Console.ReadLine()!=RightAnswerFunc())
{
  //Wrong. Retry.
}

private static string RightAnswerFunc()
{
//smth here
}
```

So is there any difference between:

- `While(Console.ReadLine()!=RightAnswerFunc())`
- `While(RightAnswerFunc()!=Console.ReadLine())`

Intuitively I would write the first way. It seems logical. But is there any real difference? Or is it just a convention?
If it doesn't matter, then does it always not matter? (i.e. fine with comparing Int32 but wrong when comparing other types).

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` will always return a `string`, therefore it doesn't really matter. Both instructions will be executed in order to get the results to be compared.

Comment: @AndreiV Pretty sure they will. For some reason this strange thought came to my mind, if the positioning could catually matter in some cases. Thanks.

Comment: Only if you expect one of them to throw an exception and halt your program execution.

Comment: @AndreiV Actually code of RightAnswerFunc() is "throw new NotImplementedException();" You have very good intuition :) [/joke]

Comment: That's just temporary, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is that it probably won't matter for most code.

Long answer is that it could very well matter depending on what you do in `RightAnswerFunc`. C# evaulates the methods from left to right, so first it calls `ReadLine()` and once that method returns the `RightAnswerFunc` will be called. This is imporant should there be any side effects in those methods, for example imagine:

```
private static string RightAnswerFunc()
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

Calling `while (Console.Readline() != RightAnswerFunc()) { }` keeps your program open until the user hits enter. Swapping the operands closes your application right away.

This is also even imporant for the logical `&&` and `||` operators, which only evaluate the operands for as long as it takes until the final expression can be evaluated to true or false.

For example `if (true || SomeMethod())` won't call the method since the result will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

In your case and ***for all single comparisons*** (regardless of the operator type and the types being compared), it does ***not*** matter. However, if you were building up logic, consider

```
bool A()
{
    return false;
}

bool B()
{
    return true;
}

//...

if (A() && B())
{
    // do something
}
```

For an AND (&&) clause to be true, all elements must be true. However, A() returns false, and the run-time (or maybe the compiler here, in an optimization step, but let's not worry about that...) won't evaluate B() at all.

The same holds true for OR (||) expressions. If any element in the clause is true, evaluated left to right, the rest of the clause won't be executed.

---

*Note. also, if there are no other calls after the `Readline()` then you application could exit immediately.*

Comment: What you said is right about `AND` and `OR`. But question is about `!=`.

Comment: I have address the single comparison FOR ALL operators. With single comparisons it _does not matter_. How much more clearer do you want it?

Comment: ... and about strings

Comment: Edited... I hope this is now okay. Thanks.

Comment: Question is not about method comparison which returns `bool`. It is related to `string` comparison.

Comment: I have stated that the _types being compared **and** the operator_ is **irrelevant** for **single comparisons** - what is it you want me to say? If you don't like the answer, down-vote it...

Comment: @Killercam Thanks, you gave a good answer. I was pretty sure it doesn't matter in my case. I was hunting after the details and other cases.

Answer (score 1):

It will be exactly the same, it is always just comparing the output of two strings.

What I would potentially do though is change it so that the compare took place completely in your RightAnswerFunc and that it returned a bool.  EG:

```
While(!RightAnswerFunc())
{
    //Wrong. Retry.
}

private static bool RightAnswerFunc()
{
    bool isValid = false;
    if(yourStringValue == Console.ReadLine())
    {
          isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Als long as you only compare two things in a single operation (e.g. only one != in the if-clause), it does not matter which way you write it.